# MYSQL - SELECT IN ( ) ORDER BY IN ( )

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

If i select like this:

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE id IN(3,4,8,1);
```

This by default will select users in this order

```
1,
3,
4,
8,
```

I would like to select them in the same order that i put IN() values so:

```
   3,
   4,
   8,
   1
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) for that

```
SELECT id 
FROM users 
WHERE id IN(3,4,8,1)
order by field(id, 3,4,8,1)
```